# Generate the module.symvers from a machine that doesn't have "make" and no path to "/usr/src"

Tags: linux, compilation, linux-kernel, makefile

I'm trying to cross-compile a LKM from Kali to a box with a very small Linux OS running. That OS doesn't have GCC, Make, and can't find the Kernel source. I need the module.symvers to cross-compile, but have no idea how to find/generate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must invoke `make modules` and then `module.symvers` will be generated.

Comment: As stated, I don't have Make on the target machine.

Comment: You must invoke `make modules` on the host machine......Where you have cross-compile tool

Comment: But don't I need the symbols of the target machine? What does it help to do `make modules` on the build machine?

Comment: @bzupnick What is the tiny linux you have ??? Can you download kernel source ????

Comment: Yes I downloaded the kernel source.

Comment: @bzupnick Can you build kernel source tree ??? Do you know commands that you must execute??? On the target machine ¿ Do you have `.config` file ?